# Limit of real function with complex variable

Tags: limits

Given a real function $f(x)$, which has
$$
\lim_{x->+\infty} f(x) = c
$$
I am wondering whether this limit still exist for
$$
\lim_{x->+\infty} f((a+bj)x) = c
$$ 
where $a > 0, b$ are constant, $x$ is real.

Complement: To be more specific, I am trying to prove such an equality
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{(jb+a)^2 x}{1+jbe^{(jb+a)x}} dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x}{1+jbe^{x}} dx 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(x)}$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$$

Let $a=-1, b=0$,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f((a+bj)x)=1$$

Edit after the constraint $a>0$ is imposed:

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{R} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)= 1$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f((1+i)x)= 0$$

Another possible example is $f(x)=Im(x)$, that is taking the imaginary part of a complex number.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that a>0.